# How to write a cron job with wget

Tags: cron, wget

I am trying to write a cron job that retrieves information from a web server using wget.

To be more specific, I am retrieving data from the National Data Buoy Center (NDBC) from the National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administrations (NOAA). This data is free to the public.

The following command successfully creates the .txt file in my directory:

```
wget https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46237.spec
```

Now I am trying to automate this command every 30 minutes by writing a cron job. I used vim to write the following code:

```
0,30 * * * * wget https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46237.spec
```

I also verified this cron job exists by running "crontab -l"

Does anyone know why this is isn't executing properly?

P.S. I am new to programming, please correct me if I am misusing any terminology. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There can be a lot of reasons but as general approach will be good to use absolute paths and forcely redirect the output of `wget` to specific file. Also is good to ignore certification check when access https. And your cron will become something like:

```
0,30 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O /tmp/my_result.file --no-check-certificate https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/data/realtime2/46237.spec
```

Above all the paths and filenames are example!

But the best practice is to create shell script (in your home directory for example) and run via cron this script

Comment: $ /usr/sbin/cron start
cron: can't open or create /var/run/cron.pid: Permission denied

Comment: I have corrected my cron, but still not getting anything. I ran "/usr/sbin/cron start", Please see above for output

Comment: @ConnorCantrell, `cron` is started as daemon and usually its not required to start it by hand as it is started when OS started. Just wait and check logs.